# How to send csv file or json data in post request in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a post request naming 'Register' which will allow users to upload .csv files or .json files I want to test the load on this API with different CSV /JSON files for different users. I have added files path in 'PLAN.CSV' .Each file contain JSON DATA-
Please guide
Request image and result image is attached here[Resquest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHHcb.png)

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIXoU.png)

[CSV CONFIG SET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJGkY.png)

Comment: How is the request payload in the browser could you please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your syntax is incorrect, the valid one for the [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) would be:

   ```
   ${__FileToString(${JSON_FILE},,)}
   ```

   Consider using [Functions Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) if you're uncertain
2. Your setup doesn't really "upload" the file, it sends the file as the HTTP [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) body, the "upload" assumes either PUT or POST with [multipart-form/data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#sending_files_using_a_formdata_object). Again if you're not sure that you're building the request correctly just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure that the file(s) you're uploading are present in ["bin" folder of your JMeter installation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you very much!! @Dmitri T,  It's effective. You found a solution to my problem. On Jmeter, I keep track of all of your posts and blogs. Thank you once more :) I'm using a POST request to upload a JSON payload. You are correct; if JSON is not available, I must use 'multipart-form/data' with a CSV file. I didn't do it; instead, I made a JSON with a recorder/blaze meter and then used CSV CONFIG SET. Thank you, it works for me.