# How to control a flow /sequence of REST API in Jmeter?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load-testing

My previous [[question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68937520/how-to-send-csv-file-or-json-data-in-post-request-in-jmeter)

Here Now I want to control the sequence of API s,
Expected - Register, Validate, Cancel and after Validate there should be a wait time of 3 secs to perform cancel. I have tried with 'Transaction Controller ' but it doesn't work.Please guide

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Either add a Constant Timer as a child of the "Cancel" request and set "Thread Delay" to `3000`

  [image]
- or add a Flow Control Action sampler between "Validate" and "Cancel" requests and configure it to "Pause" for `3000` milliseconds:

  [image]

Both options will create a 3 seconds delay between "Validate" and "Cancel" requests.

More information on implementing user delays aka ["Think Times"](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time): [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers)

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of solutions to this problem. When you need to introduce delays always consider using [JMeter Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers).

> **Note**:  Timers are processed before each sampler in the scope in
> which they are found

> To apply a timer to a single sampler, add the timer as a child element
> of the sampler. The timer will be applied before the sampler is
> executed. To apply a timer after a sampler, either add it to the next
> sampler or add it as the child of a Flow Control Action Sampler.

Use [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) to introduce delays.

**But** if you need to wait for a specific condition to be passed before proceeding to the Cancel request, consider using [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers).